# fread filesize not working

Tags: php, fopen, filesize, fread

I am trying to get filesize to use it in fread

```
$Url='https://example.com/ajax/test.php';

$params = array('http' => array(
                    'method' => 'POST',
                    'content' => 'page=1'
                ));

$ctx = stream_context_create($params);

$file = fopen($Url, 'rb', false, $ctx);
fread($file,filesize("$Url"));
```

This is not working because filesize always return 0 and length parameter must be greater than 0.

I also tryed using fstat to get filesize but it returns nothing.

Comment: Why do you expect functions to execute correctly? You don't even debug the output of them.

Comment: well, you try to get the filesize of a string that should contain a (local) filename, not an url.

Comment: RTM and it's comments: http://php.net/manual/de/function.filesize.php#92462